# jquery ui accordion and height expand dynamically

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have an accordion with two content areas each holding an input and dropdown driven by Chosen.js.

When user clicks the input field, a dropdown appears and user can select as many choices from the list to narrow the search based on the keywords selected.

My problem is the accordion h3 below the top accordion moves off to the right to make room for the input once a number of choices have been chosen (the drop down nicely drops over it no problem.

I've tried various versions of the following javascript for the accordion (changing out heightstyle) with various results but nothing that is exactly right. The dropdown needs to stay outside of the accordion area and the "any of these" "all of these" radio and check boxes need to stay visible while user is making choices.

```
jQuery( function() {
jQuery( ".accordionSearch" ).accordion( {
  heightStyle: "content",
  activate: function( event, ui ) {
if (ui.newHeader.attr('id') == 'skill-search-header') {
  which_search_string = 'skill';
      doSearch();
}
else if (ui.newHeader.attr('id') == 'project-search-header') {
  which_search_string = 'project';
      doSearch();
}
  }
} );
} );
```

[Here's my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcTfn/1/)

Comment: Your fiddle requires a username and password for 1 of the loaded external resources, may want to change that or provide said username and password.

Comment: Thank you @Chausser, I am not able to take off the password protection but I think i have managed to figure this out on my own.